# Unable to send data using POST in Python

Tags: php, python

I am trying to send data using POST from StachExchange API. I am not sure what seems to be the problem. I have checked the script, it's working fine when I try to POST data some other way. The problem seems to be with the python script. The scripts gets the data from the API but doesn't seems to be posting to "generate.php" Nonetheless here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests, json

userinput = input('Enter a keyword: ')
userinputq = input('Enter page: ')

getparams = {'page':userinputq, 'pagesize':'100', 'order':'desc', 'sort':'votes', 'intitle':userinput, 'site':'stackoverflow', 'filter': '!5-HwXhXgkSnzI0yfp0WqsC_-6BehEi(fRTZ7eg'}

r = requests.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search', params=getparams)

result = json.loads(r.text)

if result['has_more'] == False:
print("Error given.")
else:
 for looping in result['items']:

     if looping['is_answered'] == True:
       try:
          newparams = {'order':'desc', 'sort':'votes', 'site':'stackoverflow', 'filter': '!4(Yrwr)RRK6oy2JSD'}
          newr = requests.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/'+str(looping['accepted_answer_id']), params=newparams) 
          newresult = json.loads(newr.text)
          titletopost = 'Title:', looping['title']
          bodytopost = '<h1>Question:</h1><br>'+(looping['body'])+'<br>'+'Link to Question: '+(looping['link'])+'<br><br><br>'+'<h1>Answer:</h1><br>'+(newresult['items'][0]['body'])
          enterremove = bodytopost.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
          print(enterremove)
          userdata = {"secret":"Secret", "topic_title":titletopost, "body":enterremove}
          requests.post("http://www.example.com/generate.php", data=userdata)
       except KeyError: print("No answer ID found.")         

print("")
print("")
```

Can anyone please explain the problem?

Comment: You may want to fix the indent on the `print()` on the first `if` statement

Comment: It also says that requests does not exist

Comment: Yeah, thanks, fixed! And what requests? The import library? You can install it using: pip install requests

Comment: Where do I type that? I am on Windows 10

Comment: And yes, I am talking about the `import requests, json`

Comment: python -m pip install requests

Comment: So I type `-m pip install requests` into IDLE?

Comment: What version of Python do you have?

Comment: Try stringifying the data payload manually `requests.post("http://www.example.com/generate.php", data=json.dumps(userData))`

Comment: I have version 3.4.3

Comment: Actually I forgot to change "$_GET" to "$_POST" in 'generate.php' while I was testing it. Sorry for that!

Comment: Don't worry about it! As long as you have solved the problem :)

Comment: Also I just gave you +20 reputation points :)

Comment: Ruler, Use **> Path\easy_install.exe requests** if you have a windows machine, where easy_install can be found in your **Python*\Scripts** folder, if it was installed. (Note **Path\easy_install.exe** is an example, it can be C:\Python32\Scripts\easy_install.exe)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I have just gone and upvoted everything you have ever posted as well :D. I have installed it now, thanks for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127575/discussion-between-user41992-and-ruler-of-the-world).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind! There's nothing wrong with the python script. Actually I forgot to change **"$_GET"** to **"$_POST"** in '*generate.php*' while I was testing it.

Comment: Haha the code did look ok to me :D Glad it is fixed